# Manually stopping Spark Workers

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to stop a Spark worker through the terminal? I'm aware of the scripts: start-all.sh, stop-all.sh, stop-workers.sh, etc. However, everytime I run start-all.sh there seems to be residual workers from a previous Spark cluster instance that are also spawned. I know this because the Worker Id contains the date and timestamp of when the worker was created.

So when I run start-all.sh today, I see the same 7 or so workers that were created at the beginning of April.

Is there a way to kill these earlier workers? Or perhaps a way to grep for their process names?

Answer (score 3):

This has happened to me in the past and what I usually do is:

1) Find the process id:

```
ps aux | grep spark
```

2) And kill it:

```
sudo kill pid1
```

Comment: Just for simplify the output and find the process id more easily, you can type `ps ax | grep spark` or `ps -ef | grep spark`

Answer (score 0):

You can do either:

`for pid in $(ps aux | grep spark | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid; done`

or

`for pid in $(jps | grep Worker | awk '{print $1}'); do kill -9 $pid; done`

I would suggest that you use the second one so that you don't kill something accidentally since the first one will also show pid for grep and maybe something else that you might have running.

**Explanation** (might be helpful for new users):

In the pipeline, we have ps (gives us the currently running processes) or jps (jvm process status tool, which gives us the process ids for the processes in the jvm).Then we grep and according to output we grab the pid with the help of awk.

In the loop, kill command with signal -9 (SIGKILL i.e. forced termination, not recommended should be used as last resort). Bye bye process.

Answer (score 0):

To kill a spark worker using spark daemons:

```
ssh <host-name-where-worker-is-running> 
spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/spark-daemon.sh stop org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker 1
sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

To start it back again:

```
spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/spark-daemon.sh start org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker 1
```

Ideally, spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3 should be your ${SPARK-HOME}. Also, ensure to clear your memory caches when you kill the spark worker/executor